# How can I remain the page without redirect/render after post method(express)

Tags: javascript, ajax, express, pug, amazon-ses

I tried to make a page that can send e-mail with aws SES in single web page.

But the problem is I have to redirect or render after send e-mail.
Otherwise, SES keeps sending email repeatedly.
I just want to remain current position of page without refresh.

I also tried to use ajax, but it keeps show me an 500 error message.

here is my code.

--app.js

```
router.get('/email', ses.sendEmail);
```

--ses.js (param is not a problem, I just didn't put it here)

```
    exports.sendEmail =
    
        (req, res, next) => {
            
            ses.sendEmail(params, function(err, data){
                
                if(!err){
                    console.log(data.MessageId);
                    res.render('afterEmail');
            return;
                }
                else {
                    console.log(err.message);
                }
        
            })
        }
```

--ajax

```
jQuerjQuery(document).ready(function($){
  
  $("button.send").closest("form").submit(function(e) {
        
    e.preventDefault();
    
      var formData = new FormData($(this));
    
      console.log(formData);

        $.get('/email').then(function (data) {
  
        console.log(data);
  
        $('form.contact_form').css("display", "none");
  
        $('section.afterEmail').html(data);
          });
      })
  });
```

--index.pug

```
form.contact_form(method='POST' action='')
    table.submit
      tr
        td
          input.name(type='text' name='name' placeholder='Name')
      tr
        td
          input.email(type='text' name='email' placeholder='E-mail')
      tr
        td
          textarea(placeholder='Message' name='Message' rows='4' cols='50')
    button.send(type='submit') Send

    section.afterEmail
```

--afterEmail.pug

```
h1= title
```

please help me to solve this.

thanks guys.

Comment: If you dont want page refresh, AJAX is the way to go. what does the 500 error tell you

Comment: It just showed me a "500 (Internal Server Error)".

Comment: did you check the express logs to see if it gives more information